# Set Labels in Gephi from Neo4j Database

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I've got a Neo4j database I imported into Gephi, but when I click "show labels", it doesn't show any text, and when I look at a node property, the label is blank.

How do I get Gephi to set the label to one of my node properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These steps should do the trick:

1) In the Overview tab in Gephi, click the options toggle button in the lower right (the little square icon with a pointy hat)

2) Select the Labels tab

3) Click the Configure button to edit label text settings

4) You can now select any imported Neo4j node/edge attributes to be displayed instead of the blank Label value.

5) For bonus points, check out Label adjust to fix overlapping: https://gephi.org/2008/label-adjust/

Comment: Perfect! I didn't even recognize the "options" button, let alone know that's where the magic hid.

Comment: A heads up for people who are new to gephi (like me)...in version 82, in the overview tab, first you have to enable to "graph" window (click on window>graph) before you can see the options button.  I spent hours  clicking on different things before I figured it out.